# Keycloak Quickstarts is not working in the deploy Wildfly

Tags: java, spring-security, wildfly, keycloak

I used this example from Keycloak Quickstarts to do a little test from my Keycloak server and see if works.

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/app-authz-spring-security

For me it's not working, where each time than I try to connect it through the browser returns an Error 404.

I have this configuration in the application.properties:

```
server.port = 38080
keycloak.realm=FocusocKeycloak
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8080/auth
keycloak.ssl-required=external
keycloak.resource=login-provider-web
keycloak.public-client=false
keycloak.credentials.secret=secret
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].authRoles[0] = user
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].name = protected
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0] = /*

# Turn off the logs
logging.level.root=OFF
logging.level.org.springframework.boot=OFF
spring.main.banner-mode=OFF
```

And in the keycloak.json is this,

```
{
  "realm": "FocusocKeycloak",
  "auth-server-url": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "login-app",
  "verify-token-audience": true,
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "145ca6f7-19c8-4478-b092-ba685a52d985"
  },
  "use-resource-role-mappings": true,
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

Am I wrong with anything? Or am I missing anything? I didn't change any further configuration in the project downloaded from github.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the problem was that I deploy it directly in Wildfly not through spring-boot:run, so it works perfectly.